# How can I display table.column=$variable?

Tags: php, mysql

Couldn't find an answer myself. My first question here. I try to be as precise as I possibly can.

Question:

What i want basically is that the number from 'imagedisplay.number' and 'image.number' is a variable.
Is this even possible or should i do it differently?

What i got:

```
SELECT image.image
FROM image INNER JOIN imagedisplay
ON imagedisplay.number = image.number
```

What i want:

```
$x = 1

SELECT image.$x
FROM image INNER JOIN imagedisplay
ON imagedisplay.$x = image.$x
```

Comment: I can not understand your question. Your variable is in a Sql procedure or PHP? Do you want do search for number 1 in database or store the result in it?

Comment: In php and I want to search number 1 in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Join is right

```
SELECT image.image
FROM image INNER JOIN imagedisplay
ON imagedisplay.number = image.number
```

As to your comment: *I want to search number 1 in the database*

You just have to add a `where` condition where you filter the results by `$x` respectively `1`

```
SELECT image.image
FROM image INNER JOIN imagedisplay
ON imagedisplay.number = image.number
WHERE image.number = $x
```

But thats not nice, you should use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Ok I get what you're saying. Also thank you for the link. 1 remaining problem: I can't get the where function to work. I feel like its really simple but can't figure it out myself. What I've tried:                                                   SELECT image.image FROM image INNER JOIN imagedisplay
WHERE number = 1 ON imagedisplay.number = image.number                                                                                                  Table info:                                                    Table imagedisplay: number / image. Table image: number / image

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON imagedisplay.number = image.number
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4

Comment: the where condition have to be after the complete join:
`SELECT image.image FROM image INNER JOIN imagedisplay ON imagedisplay.number = image.number WHERE image.number = 1` notice that you have to write `image.number` because `number` unambiguous